# AMD Athlon 64x2 Dual Core 2.6 GHz

Tags: 64-bit, adobe

64-bit or 32-bit? I need to run graphics software such as Adobe Master Collection CS3 and MS Office Publisher. What do I need ot make this work?

Comment: Adobe software barely runs *ON Wine/PlayonLinux* only Photoshop runs mostly ok and Flash relatively fine Illustrator doesn't work, Indesign Doesn't Work and.. the rest of the suite doesn't work.Office Works on Play on Linux.

Comment: 32 if you have legacy hardware that's why it still exists, 64 if yuou have modern hardware, regardless of any other stuff.

Comment: A virtual Machine though slow would still be  better than trying to make things work with Wine.

Comment: Depending on the hardware, KVM + spice or Virtualbox have excellent performance.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of Ubuntu most would advise you start with the 64 bit version.

In terms of running your Adobe and Microsoft applications, I would either use Linux native alternates, dual boot with windows, or run windows in a virtual machine such as KVM, virtualbox, or VMware.

Comment: What about WINE?

Comment: Wine is difficult to impossible to configure, depending on the application and your knowledge of both windows and linux. You can check http://appdb.winehq.org/ , I did not see either of your applications listed there.

Comment: Well thank you. Are there any other shell options I could consider?
The reason I ask is because I am very new to Ubuntu and have been using XP for the longest time. I am very pleased with XP, but it will not run on this computer I just built. So I am using Vista (or virus) and I'm running into problems with its usability and the fact that it won't install Adobe. I wonder if it is possible at all to run the programs I need to run on Ubuntu or if I will be forced to go to a different, even less familiar OS.

Comment: If you want to run primarily Windows applications, IMO, you are going to be far better off running Windows or with virtualization. But, as you can see, it is not always so easy to install windows either (most people purchase windows pre-installed and pre-configured, so it seems easy).

Comment: Which Which of the shells that you mentioned in your initial answer, would be the best choice and where can I find them?

Comment: Shells ? you mean virtualization ? I would suggest virtualbox or KVM. KVM has a bit of a learning curve, but IMO is better supported. Virtualbox is easier to learn and has a few additional features, although the gap is narrowing.